# Remove table border in powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

The code is successfully removing table borders and is fine on screen.

While printing or print previewing, its showing some table border. How to fix it?

```
 Sub Tableformatting ()
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    Dim t As Table
      Set t = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Table
            For r = 1 To t.Rows.Count
            For c = 1 To t.Columns.Count
                With t.Cell(r, c)

                    .Borders(ppBorderTop).Transparency = 0
                    .Borders(ppBorderTop).Weight = 0
                    .Borders(ppBorderBottom).Transparency = 0
                    .Borders(ppBorderBottom).Weight = 0
                    .Borders(ppBorderLeft).Transparency = 0
                    .Borders(ppBorderLeft).Weight = 0

                    .Borders(ppBorderRight).Transparency = 0
                    .Borders(ppBorderRight).Weight = 0

                End With
            Next c
        Next r
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using

```
Sub Tableformatting()
Dim r As Long, c As Long
Dim t As Table

Set t = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Table

For r = 1 To t.Rows.Count
    For c = 1 To t.Columns.Count
        With t.Cell(r, c)
            .Borders(ppBorderTop).Transparency = 1
            .Borders(ppBorderBottom).Transparency = 1
            .Borders(ppBorderLeft).Transparency = 1
            .Borders(ppBorderRight).Transparency = 1
        End With
    Next c
Next r
End Sub
```

For some reason .Transparency = 0 only works for what is actively seen, but .Transparency = 1 works for everything you asked for. It might be a bug on Microsoft's end because I don't see why this method or .Borders.Visible = msoFalse wouldn't work just for print/print preview.

Either way I hope this helped!

Comment: Transparency takes values from 0 to 1 (where 1 is equivalent to 100% in the UI).  0 means 0% transparent, or not transparent at all.  1 means 100% transparent ... totally transparent ... invisible.  That's why 1 works here where 0 didn't.

Comment: Ah that makes perfect sense!

Comment: Using C# to turn borders on and off, I confirm that ```.Visible=MsoTrue/False``` fails in both cases (broken PPT code). But the ```.Transparency=1 or 0``` method works properly.